# Is it necessary to update code/application everytime I make changes in Database?

Tags: entity-framework

I am creating a EF for my WebAPI. I am following Code from Database approach. 
I will be using Stored Procedures.Do I have to update my application code(edmx) every time I make changes in SPs or tables?

Comment: The simple answer is **IT DEPENDS**

Comment: We will be using Azure Server for deployment. So wont be able to update code whenever we have to update a SP/table.

Comment: Let's say there is a table called *'Users'* and you want to add a new column - *'Age'*. So you are updating the table in the DB. Now you need to pass the age of the user also right? Then you have to change the code. It depends on what changes you are making on the DB.